# How to get Questions Answered

Tags: discussion

What is the best strategy to get questions answered? Also to ensure that at least one of the answer is satisficing to be accepted as the correct answer? The latter is important as some times it is possible that answers do not seam to satisfy the question fully or tangential or interpreted the question in an different light than intended and provides and answer for the reinterpreted question.

Also is a reader knows someone who might be able to answer the question how is it that you can encourage the person to get this to the attention of an expert in the area to solicit and answer?

Answer (score 3):

When you click on the question, as if you are going to answer it, this appears as a clickable link to share the question.

Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

What do you think of sharing some of our good questions that no one seems to know the answer to on Buddhist group pages on Facebook and Google+?

On the plus side, it could bring in new participants. On the minus side, I'm not sure of how to quickly initiate those coming from discussion style forums to the more strict Q & A format of SE.

Comment: Sharing is a good idea but first must be sure that the other community likes this kind of sharing.

Comment: That's a good point @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala. I hadn't considered it might be seen as an attempt to draw participation away from the other group.

Answer (score 2):

One strategy is to put a 'bounty' on the question: click on 'start a bounty' under the question.

See [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

I find it useful to edit questions that aren't getting enough attention. If no one is answering then maybe the question needs to be clarified or refined or maybe refocussed. This also has the happy side effect of bumping it back to the top of the home page.